# Stackoverflow error in Spring's (3.2.0) ConfigurationClassEnhancer after upgrading to Java 7

Tags: java, spring, configuration, java-7, spring-annotations

We have a couple of `@Configuration` annotated classes, the application is working fine on sun-jdk-6,but after upgrading to oracle-jdk-7 a SO error happens.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory' defined in class path resource [com/egnyte/filestore/cache/CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public java.lang.Object com.egnyte.filestore.cache.CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider.get()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:297)
    at com.egnyte.filestore.cache.CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6b65bac9.get(<generated>)
    at com.egnyte.filestore.cache.CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider.get(CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider.java:22)
    at com.egnyte.filestore.cache.CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6b65bac9.CGLIB$get$0(<generated>)
    at com.egnyte.filestore.cache.CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6b65bac9$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1a8904d5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:285)
    at com.egnyte.filestore.cache.CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6b65bac9.get(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[SNAP...]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:297)
    at foo.bar.cache.CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6b65bac9.get(<generated>)
    at foo.bar.cache.CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider.get(CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider.java:22)
    at foo.bar.cache.CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6b65bac9.CGLIB$get$0(<generated>)
    at foo.bar.cache.CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6b65bac9$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1a8904d5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:285)
    at foo.bar.cache.CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6b65bac9.get(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029)
```

Note that  foo.bar.cache.CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider.get(CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider.java:22) points to a line of code with the `@Configuration` annotation, not the actual `get()` implementation.

Default proxy mode is "no".
The class has nothing fancy:

```
@Configuration
class CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider implements Provider<Foo<?>> { 

    @Inject
    private List<Pair<String, Integer>> peers;

    @Override
    @Bean(name = CACHE_MANAGER_PEER_PROVIDER_FACTORY)
    public Foo<?> get() { 
        return new Foo(peers);    
    }
}
```

Is this a bug in Spring? Is it possible to disable the enhancer?

Comment: What version of Spring? Can you post more from that stack trace (maybe two repetitions)? Also, some relevant piece of code.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - version is in title, added some more stacktrace and the class in question

Comment: Couldn't find anything similar reported on Spring JIRA. I would suggest a more recent version of Spring. Also, if you can reproduce this in a simpler, standalone project it would be great (maybe creating a JIRA issue, as well).

Comment: @AndreiStefan - upgrading spring is not an option for now, I guess filing a bug is the way to go then

Comment: Filling a bug, but it would be more helpful if your test case is as complete as possible. And, also, it has more credibility if this test case is done against one of the latest versions of Spring.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - I need this solved for 3.2.0, it's simply not practical to upp spring version now

Comment: You know best, I was just making suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this is definately a bug in Spring.

To fix this remove the `Provider<>` interface, and therfore make the `get()` method a regular one and not overriden (it seems it's the Provider interface which is messing up internal Spring plumbing, not the method being an override per se). So much for making your dependencies jsr-330 compatibile.

```
@Configuration
class CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider 
  //implements Provider<Foo<?>> 
    { 

    @Inject
    private List<Pair<String, Integer>> peers;

    //@Override
    @Bean(name = CACHE_MANAGER_PEER_PROVIDER_FACTORY)
    public Foo<?> get() { 
        return new Foo(peers);    
    }
}
```

Works!

As an alternative solution change the `@Configuration` to `@Component` or `@Named`

```
@Named
class CacheManagerPeerProviderConfigurationProvider implements Provider<Foo<?>> 
    { 

    @Inject
    private List<Pair<String, Integer>> peers;

    @Override
    @Bean(name = CACHE_MANAGER_PEER_PROVIDER_FACTORY)
    public Foo<?> get() { 
        return new Foo(peers);    
    }
}
```

Resolved [in SPR-11830](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11830)